# Python- Modifying a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Now I know it's usually not feasible to modify a csv file as you are reading from it so you need to create a new csv file and write to it. The problem I'm having is preserving the original order of the data.

The input csv file looks like follows:

```
C1       C2         C3
apple    BANANA     Mango
pear     PineApple  StRaWbeRRy
```

I want to turn all the data into lower case and output a new csv file that looks like:

```
C1       C2         C3
apple    banana     mango
pear     pineapple  strawberry
```

So far I can iterate through the input csv file and turn all the values into lower case but I don't know how to rewrite it back into a csv file in that format. The code I have is:

```
def clean (input)
  aList = []
  file = open(input, "r")
  reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
  next(reader, None) # Skip the header but I want to preserve it in the output csv file
  for row in reader:
     for col in row:
        aList.append(col.lower())
```

So now I have a list with all the lowercase data, how do I rewrite it back into a csv file of the same format (same number of rows and columns) as the input including the header row that I skipped in the code.

Comment: Don't bother saving the lines to a list. Just open both your input & output files at the same time, so you can write each modified line as you create it. In fact, I wouldn't even bother using the `csv` module for this. It's a pity you need to preserve the case of the header line, otherwise you could just process the whole file with the `tr` program (if you're using a Unix-like OS).

Comment: With pandas: `pd.read_csv(input).apply(str.lower).to_csv(input)`

Comment: I just noticed that your code specifies `,` as the delimiter, but your sample data uses whitespace. Please explain!

Comment: @PM2Ring You could still use command line tools if you use the head command to grab the header.

Comment: @PM2Ring I was just representing the data that way here. The input is in a csv file with those rows and columns. Having said that, I too don't know why the delimiter , works but it does! It was a mistake initially but it works just fine

Comment: It works because the `csv` module treats the whole line as a single field because it doesn't see a comma.

Comment: @ Tim True, but it's slightly messier. But I guess it'd still be faster than doing it in Python.

Answer (score 11):

**Pandas way:**

Read the file using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and get the dataframe. Then you can simply use [lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower)

```
import pandas as pd

def conversion(text):
    return text.lower()
    

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
df[column_name] = df[column_name].map(conversion)
```

Or even a single liner:

```
df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda x: x.lower()) # If you have nan or other non-string values, you may need to convert x to string first like str(x).lower()
```

Then you can save it using [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is change the case of the data and preserve everything else you might be best to skip the csv module and just use a 
straight file eg:

```
# Open both files
with open("infile.csv") as f_in, open("outfile.csv", 'w') as f_out:
    # Write header unchanged
    header = f_in.readline()
    f_out.write(header)

    # Transform the rest of the lines
    for line in f_in:
        f_out.write(line.lower())
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use csv module for all then use following code snippet.

```
import os
import csv


def clean(input):
    tmpFile = "tmp.csv"
    with open(input, "r") as file, open(tmpFile, "w") as outFile:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')
        header = next(reader)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in reader:
            colValues = []
            for col in row:
                colValues.append(col.lower())
            writer.writerow(colValues)
    os.rename(tmpFile, input)
```

Comment: That's correct, then we need to create another file and copy the file finally.

Comment: You should fix the whitespace indent. You are using 1, 2, 3 and 4 spaces at different points. Python will not like this!

Comment: @Tim I'm using ideone which has a problem. I've fixed this using PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way that i found is as follows
let the initial `CSV` file name be `test.csv`

```
with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    with open('cleaned.csv','w') as ff:
        ff.write(f.readline())
        ff.write(f.read().lower())
```

the above code will create a new csv with all lower case

Comment: Ok, that works properly now. But like your earlier version, it unnecessarily reads the whole file into a string. Plus it uses more RAM to do the string concatenation, as Tim mentions. But I guess that's probably ok unless the file is huge, and changing the case of the whole file at once _is_ more efficient than doing it line by line.

Comment: You would want to avoid the string concatenation. If this is a large file you are going have to allocate enough memory for the whole file, and then a second time to concatenate the header.

Comment: so, instead of concatenating, i should directly write it to file? @Tim

Comment: @user8898218 Yes. Strings are immutable in python so concatenation causes a new str to be instantiated and the contents of two strings being concatenated to be copied in.