# Python apply a lambda function into a csv file(Large files)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to apply a this function `hideEmail` to a specific column of my `csv` file (large file) using python

Example of function :

```
def hideEmail(email):
    #hide email
    text = re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', email)
    return text
```

Csv file (large file > 1gb):

```
    id;Name;firstName;email;profession
    100;toto;tata;test@test.com;developer
    101;titi;tete;test@test.com;doctor
    ..
    ..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit hard to know without the data frame, but you can try:

```
import pandas as pd #import pandas
df = pd.read_csv('enter_file_path_here') #read the data

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: hideEmail(x))
#if you want to make it back to a csv:
df.to_csv('name.csv')
```

Comment: Question is how to apply on csv file, not on pandas dataframe. I think you should include how to read and write pandas dataframe as well

Comment: Right you are, I will edit it accordingly :)

Comment: I think the question is directed to a Pandas Dataframe

Comment: You don't need the `lambda` here.

Answer (score 4):

Load the `csv` data into a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/csv')
```

Then you can just use `pd.Series.str.replace` directly as it supports regex by default:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[^@.]', 'x'), axis=1)
```

That said, if all you want to do is changing a large `csv` file, `pandas` is probably an overkill.. You might have a [look](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/using-sed-to-find-and-replace-complex-string-preferrably-with-regex) at `sed`. Here's one example:

```
sed -E 's/(\w+)@(\w+)/xxx@xxx/' /path/to/file.csv > /path/to/new_file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks@FelipeLanza but i have others functions in python to apply, and unfortunately there is no regex, so i cant use sed

Comment: It most certainly does support regex. Might have a look here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions.

Answer (score 3):

**Using pandas**

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47151946/8522619) in a previous question to apply a function passed as parameter.

To export the dataframe obtained, use `to_csv` function described [here](https://datatofish.com/export-dataframe-to-csv/)

```py
import pandas as pd

def hideEmail(email):
    #hide email
    text = re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', email)
    return text 
    

column_name = "email"

df = pd.read_csv(r'Path of your CSV file\File Name.csv')
df[column_name] = df[column_name].map(hideEmail)
df.to_csv(r'Path where you want to store the exported CSV file\File Name.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in `map()` function to get it done as follows:

```
def hideEmail(email):
    #hide email
    text = re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', email)
    return text


with open('path/to/csvfile', 'r') as file:
     lines = [l.strip().split(';') for l in file.readlines()]

modifiedlines = []       # to store lines after email field is modified 

for i in lines[1:]:         # iterating from index 1 as index 0 is header
    i[3] = hideEmail(i[3])       # as email field is at index 3
    modifiedlines.append(';'.join(i))     # appending modified line

with open('path/to/csvfile', 'w') as file:
     file.writelines(modifiedlines)            # writing the lines back to file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method to map the function to each line of the file:

```
import re

def hideEmail(email):
    #hide email
    text = re.sub(r'[^@.]', 'x', email)
    return text 

with open('file.csv', 'r') as r:
    r = map(hideEmail, r.readlines())

with open('file2.csv', 'w') as f:
    for line in r:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

---

EDIT *(credits to juanpa.arrivillaga for pointing it out)*:

The `r = map(hideEmail, r.readlines())` can be replaced with just `r = map(hideEmail, r)`.

Comment: no need for `r.readlines()` just `r = map(hideEmail, r)` works

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for informing me.

Comment: @AnnZen how i can specify  a column name to apply my lamda function ?

Comment: This will replace everything in the line that isn't `@` or `.`, this solution is definitely missing the columns/fields aspect of the delimited input.